weird bone rotation
I made a cycle animation of a character going up stairs, but at some point the toe rotates, I don't know why. Here is a screenshot

and here's the file of my project


Looking at the graph editor shows that the curve pattern created by your keyframes is additively repeated after the keyframes:

Making curves cyclic is done only via curve modifiers. So if you select your curve and look in the sidebar's modifiers tab, you can see this:

As you can see here, the After Mode is set to Repeat With Offset, hence the animation is additively cycling. I guess you did this because you wanted the position of the character to keep moving up the stairs, but did not consider that only the character's motion needs to cycle additively, while the other bones only need to repeat the motion as it is. The issue is visible only on bones like your left toe because its animation isn't cyclic: the first and last keyframes have an offset so offset cycling will increment the keyframes at each repetition whereas the right toe have the same first and last keyframes, so there is no offset to be introduced there. See the difference in the X rotation of your left and right toes:

You could just fix that toe's rotation keyframes to make it cycle perfectly, and it would work as is. And check for any other bone that have a similar issue. But that would mean looking in the graph to hunt any curve that unexpectedly offsets, and it can be long and tedious if you have lots of them.
You could manually change the modifiers' After modes to Repeat Motion, but since you made this mistake on multiple curves, the fastest solution would be to select all the bones in the viewport that should repeat the motion as is (I reckon all except the torso), then all their curves in the graph editor, and call the Set F-Curve Extrapolation menu with ⇧ ShiftE to first Clear Cyclic and then Make Cyclic again, which creates the same modifier but with Repeat Motion on all modes.
You will need to adapt some animation curves, here for the left toe you need to make the keyframes cycle from start to end.

Great! I'll look into it. Thank you so much !
